# neo4j use Load CSV to read data from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, neo4j, google-cloud-storage

My original data is from Bigquery. I have created a dag job to extract the relevant fields data based on a "WHERE" condition into a csv file stored in Google Cloud Storage

As a next step, I am aiming to use "LOAD CSV WITH EHADERS FROM gs://link-to-bucket/file.csv to read the data from the CSV to Neo4j database

It seems however that I cannot just give the the gcs uri as the CSV link. Is there anyway to establish a secure connection to read the file, other then making the the bucket public?

My attempt

```
uri = "gs://link-to-bucket/file.csv"
def create_LP_query(uri):
    query_string = f"""
        LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM '{uri}' AS row
        MERGE (l:Limited_Partner:Company {{id: row.id}})
        SET l.Name = row.Name """
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, you would have to create a Neo4j plugin that acts as a new ProtocolHandler.

I did one in the past for S3, you might take it as inspiration, it can be similar for GS.

https://github.com/ikwattro/neo4j-load-csv-s3-protocol